# How to login a website using chromedriver with multiple pfx certificate installed

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver, pfx

I have multiple pfx certificate (personal information exchange) installed on my system. When I have to login with chrome I just choose which cert to choose in (Windows Security) pop up window that says select a certificate. How can I achieve this(choosing a certificate) functionality in selenium chrome driver.

Two ways that I came across while searching is 
1) creating a different profile for every cert (which is not scalable if I have 1000s of cert on production server.)
2) Using PhantomJS Web browser implementation:

For which I am doing:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ImmutableMap<String, String> commandLineArguments = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
        .put("web-security", "false")
        .put("ssl-protocol", "any")
        .put("ignore-ssl-errors", "true")
        .put("webdriver-loglevel", "DEBUG")
        .put("ssl-client-certificate-file", certificatePath)
        .put("ssl-client-key-passphrase", certificatePassword)
        .build();
String[] params = commandLineArguments.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> String.format("--%s=%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .toArray(new String[0]);

cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, params);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(cap);
driver.get(Url);
```

But it is giving me blank page. I suspect, I am using "ssl-client-key-passphrase" for Personal information exchange file that states "password".. How can I specify password on chrome capabilities.? Or how can I code chromedriver to choose cert to login secure website?

Update 1: 
I tried with adding registry setting like below and restarted system.
[image]

Update 2:
I had to convert pfx cert to pem file format to make it work.

Comment: It possible to select a certificate by setting the [AutoSelectCertificateForUrls](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls) policy in the preferences. For the exact syntax, select the certificate manually and have a look at the preferences in the profile. Navigate to chrome://version/ to get the folder.

Comment: Thanks @FlorentB. I am trying to add HKey_CURRENT_USER->Software->Policies->Google->Chrome->AutoSelectCertificateForUrls: Value: 1: Data:"{"pattern":"https://www.example.com","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"certificate issuer name"}}}"  But its not working ...

Comment: check the preference file for the default syntax. it should be something like `"profile.managed_auto_select_certificate_for_urls": `